# Setting Image Source using Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image

My razor call for setting an image source works. My jQuery method returns data as a garbled url: ����

My HTML code works on page refresh:

```
<img id="profileWindowPictureContent" src="@Url.Action("GetLargeProfilePic", "Home")"/>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$.get("Home" + "GetLargeProfilePic", function (data) {
                        $("#profileWindowPictureContent").attr("src", data);
                    });
```

My controller returns a byte array:

```
return File(ImageToByte(bitmap1), "image/png");
```

I'm wondering why my jQuery code doesn't work because they seem to be identical in what they do.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a file not a url from the ajax call. The url you use in the ajax call is what you should set as the src attribute of the img element.